# Compare two complexity functions by taking logarithm?

Tags: algorithm, math

I found that taking the logarithm of both sides when comparing two functions asymptotically is a usual technique(according to some solutions to the problems for the CLRS book).

But does it always hold that the asymptotic relation of two functions after taking their logarithm indicates their original asymptotic relation?

I kind of doubt if it works when comparing two exponential functions.

For example log(3^n) = nlog3,  log(2^n) = nlog2, then it should indicate that O(2^n) and O(3^n) are on the same level of running time, which is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asymptotic bounds implicitly include a multiplicative constant which is ignored.

Formally, `f(n) = O(g(n))` means that you can find `N` and `C` such that `n > N => f(n) < C.g(n)`.

When taking the logarithm, the multiplicative constant become an additive one, `log(f(n)) < log(C) + log(g(n))`, and it isn't true that `f(n) = O(g(n)) <=> log(f(n)) = O(log(g(n)))`.

So if you compare two complexities by their logarithms, you cannot drop a multiplicative constant, but an additive one, and `n.Log(3)` indeed differs from `n.Log(2).`

Similarly, `O(n²)` and `O(n³)` differ because `2.Log(n)` and `3.Log(n)` don't have the same cefficient.